# Using shopify store front api, get webUrl by mutation checkoutCreate, open this url in browser. But need login again

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

we choose to use weburl in webview in native app && shopify.It is headless. currrently we have got the weburl by checkoutCreate mutation. But we find in the browse customer has to login again instead of auto login. How could auto login by webUrl?